# How to downgrade NDK to r8e

Tags: android, android-ndk, downgrade

I migrated an android project from Eclipse to Android Studio, and updated the NDK. When I build the solution I had this error:

> Error:(61, 2) error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4TU8.png)

I can't find any solution, so I am thinking that I have to downgrade the NDK.
Is there another way to resolve this? If not, how can I downgrade my NDK to r8e?

Comment: It's an error in your code, you should resolve that, instead of going back to a 4 year old NDK.

Comment: My code work fine on eclipse, but on android studio i got this error ...

Comment: Eclipse might be using an old compiler, or old version of the NDK.

Comment: That's why i'm asking this question ...

Comment: Why don't you just fix the error in your code instead? If `buf` is a plain string without any format specifiers, use `__android_log_write` instead of `__android_log_print`.

Comment: It's the same error, this was a warning on eclipse, that's why i should downgrade the NDK.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In order to downgrade your ndk, you will have to pull it from the internet with **wget** and move it into your Android SDK dir:

- wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r13b-darwin-x86_64.zip
- unzip android-ndk-r13b-darwin-x86_64.zip
- mv android-ndk-r13b/ ${ANDROID_HOME}/ndk-bundle

Comment: When I do this .. with version 16 it still says 17 when I reopen AS?

Comment: @justdan0227 Check your project structure in Android Studio, and make sure you are pointing to your custom downloaded NDK, not AS default one.

Comment: Thanks.. I had to uninstall the NDK, then copy the 16 version over to the android home folder and go into AS and point the NDK folder to the 16 version.  The check mark in the SDK tools is still un-checked, however my cpp code now compiles

Comment: If you have an existing NDK, better remove that `rm -rf $ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle` and then `mv` the new one onto it e.g. `mv android-ndk-r16b $ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle`